# Device is not showing up in IBM Mobilefirst console after deleting it manually once

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I manually deleted a device in Mobilefirst console. Now it is not reappearing on the list of devices in the console even after reinstalling the app on the phone.

How do i get the device to connect to the server again?

Answer (score 1):

For a device record to appear in the Devices section of the MFP Console, the application installed on the device must first connect to the server.

I have confirmed this is working as expected by:

1. New project and application + iPhone environment
2. Add WL.Client.connect to wlCommonInit
3. Test in iOS Simulator
4. Check that the device appears in the Devices table
5. Delete device from the device table
6. Run the app again in the iOS Simulator
7. Refresh Devices table - device re-appears

Comment: Thank you Idan. Now it looks like the app is not able to connect to server as I am unable to invoke adapters from the app. Everything was working fine before i removed the device in console. Any idea whats going on

Comment: Because your text is only theoretical and w/out any error logs, no, I can't help you. Add WL.Client.connect to your code, check what is the error.